# How to Pass Msgbox Button Options dynamically in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create msgbox with dynamic options.
That is the message, buttons, icons and title will be changing dynamically.

when Creating msgbox I am trying to imitate the following msgbox pattern through vba code

`Msgbox "Test Data Completed",vbAbortRetryIgnore + vbInformation, "My Msgbox Title"`

I am stucking on adding two options together (vbAbortRetryIgnore + vbInformation). These two options will be dynamic based on user selection.

what i tried is

```
msgdata = "Test Data Completed"
msgbuttons = "vbAbortRetryIgnore + vbInformation"
msgtitle = "My Msgbox Title"

Msgbox msgdata,msgbuttons,msgtitle
```

and i got Type Mismatch Error.
any help will be appreciated

Comment: **Msgbox** buttons are actually numeric values. When you put quotes round a text, you are changing it to a string. Have a look at this page to figure out which numeric value you need to send: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/msgbox-function

Comment: You need to remove the quotation mark in : msgbuttons = vbAbortRetryIgnore + vbInformation

Comment: yes exactly, if i use like this it works
 
msgbuttons = vbAbortRetryIgnore + vbInformation

But the names are getting populated dynamically from the drop down. When i store as numeric I am unable to use Plus (+) Symbol to concatenate two options. If i place the names its taking as string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use a helper function that translates the string into proper `VbMsgBoxStyle` enumeration value:

```
Function GetvBMsgInfo(strngVbInfo) As VbMsgBoxStyle
    Select Case strngVbInfo
        Case "vbAbortRetryIgnore"
            GetvBMsgInfo = VbMsgBoxStyle.vbAbortRetryIgnore
        Case "vbApplicationModal"
            GetvBMsgInfo = VbMsgBoxStyle.vbApplicationModal
        Case "vbCritical"
            GetvBMsgInfo = VbMsgBoxStyle.vbCritical
        Case "vbDefaultButton2"
            GetvBMsgInfo = VbMsgBoxStyle.vbDefaultButton1
        Case "vbDefaultButton1"
            GetvBMsgInfo = VbMsgBoxStyle.vbDefaultButton2
        Case "vbDefaultButton3"
            GetvBMsgInfo = VbMsgBoxStyle.vbDefaultButton3
        Case "vbDefaultButton4"
            GetvBMsgInfo = VbMsgBoxStyle.vbDefaultButton4
        Case "vbExclamation"
            GetvBMsgInfo = VbMsgBoxStyle.vbExclamation
        Case "vbInformation"
            GetvBMsgInfo = VbMsgBoxStyle.vbInformation
        Case "vbMsgBoxHelpButton"
            GetvBMsgInfo = VbMsgBoxStyle.vbMsgBoxHelpButton
        Case "vbMsgBoxRight"
            GetvBMsgInfo = VbMsgBoxStyle.vbMsgBoxRight
        Case "vbMsgBoxRtlReading"
            GetvBMsgInfo = VbMsgBoxStyle.vbMsgBoxRtlReading
        Case "vbMsgBoxSetForeground"
            GetvBMsgInfo = VbMsgBoxStyle.vbMsgBoxSetForeground
        Case "vbOKCancel"
            GetvBMsgInfo = VbMsgBoxStyle.vbOKCancel
        Case "vbOKOnly"
            GetvBMsgInfo = VbMsgBoxStyle.vbOKOnly
        Case "vbRetryCancel"
            GetvBMsgInfo = VbMsgBoxStyle.vbRetryCancel
        Case "vbSystemModal"
            GetvBMsgInfo = VbMsgBoxStyle.vbSystemModal
        Case "VbMsgBoxStyle.vbYesNo"
            GetvBMsgInfo = VbMsgBoxStyle.vbYesNo
        Case "vbYesNoCancel"
            GetvBMsgInfo = VbMsgBoxStyle.vbYesNoCancel
     End Select
End Function
```

that you'll exploit in your main code as follows:

```
msgdata = "Test Data Completed"
msgbuttons = GetvBMsgInfo("vbAbortRetryIgnore") + GetvBMsgInfo("vbInformation")
msgtitle = "My Msgbox Title"
MsgBox msgdata, msgbuttons, msgtitle
```